# How do you hide tables with no visible rows with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I've got so far, but the second line does not work because apparently you can't concatenate **this** with a selector:

```
$(".report-table").each(function () {
    var numOfVisibleRows = $(this + 'tr:visible').length;
    if (numOfVisibleRows == 0)
        $(this).hide();
    else
        $(this).show();
});
```

Any ideas?

---

Edit: here is the HTML for the table.  There will be multiple tables like this and sometimes I will have hidden all of the table's rows with JQuery `hide()`:

```
<table class="report-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Weather Report</td>
            <td>This report lists weather data.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `this` is an entire HTML element, what exactly are you trying to concatenate? Can you show your HTML to let us see a working example?

Comment: In line 2 I want to essentially say "tell me how many visible rows there are in the current table in the each loop".  This doesn't appear to work: $(this + 'tr:visible').length;

Comment: ok, got it, would be easy to help if you show Html, please

Comment: probably your answer will be something like this: `$(this).find("tr:visible").length` but I'm not sure without HTML

Comment: I added html.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var numOfVisibleRows = $(this + 'tr:visible').length;
```

with

```
var numOfVisibleRows = $(this).find('tr:visible').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look if this helps you. 
Use the `table` that in this case is the context (`this`) to find it's visible `tr` childrens.

But I don't know if you want to check only `tr` from `tbody` or from `thead` too... (tell me and I edit my answer if needed)

Note that for the example I created two tables, but one doesn't have any visible `tr`, so it is hidden;

```js
$(".report-table").each(function () {
      var numOfVisibleRows = $(this).find('tr:visible').length;
      if (numOfVisibleRows == 0)
          $(this).hide();
      else
          $(this).show();
});
```

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Table 1
<table class="report-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Weather Report</td>
            <td>This report lists weather data.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
Table 2 (will be hidden)
<table class="report-table">
    <thead>   
        <tr style="display:none">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>  
        <tr style="display:none">
            <td>Weather Report</td>
            <td>This report lists weather data.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you hiding the entire table if no row or a particular row in the table?

Comment: Yes, if all of the table's rows have been hidden with hide() then the table should be hidden.